# "Have not heard" vs "Had not heard"

Tags: perfect-constructions

"have never heard" or "had never heard": Which one should I use in the sentence?

"Today, I attended a birthday ceremony. I was there for a few hours. The place was decorated well. There I heard a song that had a very good melody. it is so amazaing that I can not forget the melody of the song. I ***had never/have never heard*** that song before."

Answer (score 2):

The present perfect designates a present state arising out of a past event: in the present, when you are describing the song, you obviously **have** heard it, so you must use the past perfect, *had never*, here, to designate your state before you heard it.

Comment: @user254288 - In that case, I think either *had* or *have* is appropriate, because the situation is still current, although the song is finished.  The longer ago and more complete the situation is, the more *had* is correct.